# Gostaria da opinião de vocês sobre um Diagrama Entidade-Relacionamento de um script do POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, diagrama

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade cujo o objetivo é fazer um banco de dados de uma biblioteca particular e elaborar um diagrama entidade-relacionamento do mesmo , fiz o script no postgresql mas tenho muita dificuldade na hora de passar a fazer o diagrama no brmodelo, principalmente na parte de cardinalidade, poderiam me ajudar? Aqui está o meu script da biblioteca. Logo abaixo postarei o DER.

```
CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
DESCRICAO VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE EDITORA(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AUTOR(
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE LIVRO(
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  NOME VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  ID_CATEGORIA INT,
  ID_AUTOR INT,
  ID_EDITORA INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_CATEGORIA) REFERENCES CATEGORIA(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_AUTOR)     REFERENCES AUTOR(ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_EDITORA) REFERENCES EDITORA(ID)
);
```

O DER:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá Emanoel! Seja bem-vindo à nossa comunidade. Vou elaborar uma resposta e já já publico para você.

Comment: Obrigado, Mateus! Aguardando :D

Comment: Sua DML não corresponde ao diagrama. De acordo com sua DML um livro está relacionado a 0 ou 1 categoria (idem autor e editora). Em seu diagrama um livro está relacionado a N categorias (idem autor e editora). Para implementar um relacionamento N:N você precisa criar uma tabela auxiliar em seu modelo físico, assim deveria existir uma tabela Livro-Autor que relacionasse cada autor com todos os seus livros e cada livro com todos os seus autores (idem categoria e editora). Seu modelo prevê que um livro possa ter diversas editoras?

Comment: opa amigo, editei as cardinalidades. seria dessa forma ?

Comment: @anonimo me perdoe a correção: DDL (Data Definition Language). DML é Manipulation (Manipulação dos dados, não das estruturas). Criação de tabelas é DDL ;-)

Comment: @Mateus: correto. Falha minha.

Comment: @emanoel: agora corresponde à sua DDL, resta saber se corresponde a realidade sendo modelada, mas você não postou nada que pudesse elucidar este pontos. Por exemplo no mundo real um livro pode ter diversos autores e um autor pode escrever diversos livros, seria um relacionamento N:N.

Comment: No brmodelo (que eles pedem pra gente fazer) não existe relacionamento N:N, o correto então seria 0:N?

Comment: Um relacionamento (A) N:N (B) é traduzido, no modelo físico, em (A) 0:N (A-B) N:0 (B), ou seja é criada uma tabela intermediária com a combinação das chaves estrangeiras. Não conheço este tal de brmodelo mas pode ser que você já tenha que criar estas tabelas intermediárias nele.

Answer (score 0):

O MER (modelo entidade relacionamento) deve ser o ponto de partida para você
Elaborar seu exercício. Claro, mais tarde você desenvolverá seu próprio
Método para poder mapear certinho as entidades, seus relacionamentos e transformar
Is

Com a prática, você vai perceber que é muito mais fácil visualizar o modelo de maneira inversa (do banco para o modelo e perceber as deficiências).

Ao invés de responder sua pergunta por completo e, aliás projetar isso depende muito do nível que você quer chegar, podemos simplificar demais ou deixar completo demais (esse é o risco que toda a modelagem corre), vou me propor a responder sua pergunta de uma maneira que te ensine a refletir sobre a abstração e modelagem. É isso que você está precisando pelo que percebi na sua pergunta. E não é difícil.

Vamos lá...

***Substantivos tendem a ser Entidades no Modelo:**
**Verbos tendem a ser papéis / relacionamentos***

**Substantivos: Livro, Autor, Editora**

Agora vamos pensar nos verbos para enxergar as relações entre as entidades (tudo no singular)

Livro é CLASSIFICADO em Categoria <<>> Categoria CLASSIFICA livro

Autor REDIGE Livro <<>> Livro é REDIGIDO por Autor

Tradutor TRADUZ Livro <<>> Livro é TRADUZIDO por Tradutor

(Mas porque precisamos pensar nos tradutores revisores etc? Porque num sistema de biblioteca a classificação considera diversos dados, olhe a ficha catalográfica de um livro).

Editora PUBLICA Livro
Livro é PUBLICADO por Editora

Quando o livro é publicado, existe uma edição! Portanto não é o Livro que é publicado, e sim a EDIÇÃO dele, que possui, número, data etc.

Agora, vamos observar melhor as relações

A Editora publica de fato o Livro? Não, fisicamente a publicação está associada a uma edição que tem tiragem, edição, data, revisão e muitos outros atributos.

Autor redige livro? Como fica co-autor? E o tradutor?
Não seria melhor ao invés de ter uma Entidade chamada AUTOR ter uma chamada pessoa, e ela assume um papel de participação? Opa! Participação? Em quê? Participação no Livro.

Então veja um exemplo apenas para as entidades:

PESSOA <<<< PARTICIPAÇÃO >>>>> LIVRO

O resto vou deixar para você terminar seu trabalho ;-)
(Treine bastante modelagem!)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora a bomba para você pensar: **
MAS NO MEU MODELO COMO FICARIA SE NA SEGUNDA EDIÇÃO O TRADUTOR fosse outra pessoa de um determinado livro? Aliás, e se trocássemos o nome do relacionamento Participação para "Edição"? (agora é hora de você se exercitar por aí :-D)

Comment: Opa, Mateus. Agradeço muito sua atençao e dicas. de acordo com meus colegas da faculdade esse modelo ai nao é aceito, tbm nao vi ele nas aulas ou no livro. Tem que ser DER criado no BrModelo, seguindo os conceitos desse que postei :(

Comment: @emaonel.exe MER é uma coisa DER é outra. Quando vi suas tabelas, logo notei que vc não pensou na modelagem CONCEITUAL que é usando o MER. O DER vem depois. Faça esse exercício da forma como estou te orientando, não para entregar, para aprender. Entregar, não é o objetivo final. Aliás o BrModelo é inútil nas empresas. Nem deveria ser ensinado mais na graduação. Porque além dele ser cheio de bugs, funcionar só no Windows e quando vc dá um control z nele some tudo (em algumas versões) não tem a notação mais clássica da modelagem que é a do Peter Chen. Mostre essa resposta ao seu professor.

Comment: @emaonel.exe essa aula deve servir para você entender melhor: https://course.ccs.neu.edu/cs3200sp18s2/download/L08-ER.pdf

Comment: Ok. Vou dar uma olhada. Obg